# SAS Enterprise Miner Associaton Rules generation

Tags: sas, associations, data-mining, rules, enterprise-miner

I want to perform Association Rules on this dataset http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/. It's a dataset with customers and y is the result, if the campaign persuaded them to subscribe to a product or not.
[image]
and the rest that didn't fit in the first image
[image]
I added an ID column in the dataset so when I am running the Association Node it doesn't generate any rules. In Properties I have ID as id, y(which is the subscription result yes or no) as Target and everything else as Inputs. Role is set to Transaction. I tried with 2 and 4 Association Items.

But it gives me: There are no rules that match the specified constraints.
Any idea what should I change to have some rules?

Thanks and have a happy new year.

Comment: Your data doesn't appear conducive to association rules. This is typically done for purchases, to see what items a person buys together, ie beer and diapers from the infamous Walmart example. Since you have a yes/no binary outcome this is a different type of problem. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have to produce Rules from this specific dataset.  For example, with R, I managed to produce these kind of rules:
{marital=married,default=no} => {y=no}
housing=yes,previous=0 => {y=no}
But data mining in general and especially SAS is new to me so I don't know how to handle this problem

Comment: Ok. Then please at least post a sample of your data. Do you actually expect people (me) to download and figure out how to process/read a file just to answer your question? Transposing data is a trivial task and there should be a task in EM. But without seeing your data we can't make recommendations as to what should be done. Also, although you obviously can do this, doesn't mean you should. I recommend decision trees instead.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I added two screenshots of the first ten entries.

Answer (score 3):

"Everything else as inputs" does not sound like you want an association rule algorithm. The Enterprise Miner node expects data in a format like this:

```
id    item
 1    Apple
 1    Orange
 1    Pear
 2    Banana
```

It does not seem like your data is in that format; hence, you are not getting any rules.

Comment: PS.I have some variables rejected that do not interest me in building rules.
So how could I edit my dataset in order to be in that format?

Comment: @linous . . . You need to unpivot the data to get multiple rows for each customer with a value for each column you want.  I'm not sure if EM has such functionality built-in, but you can readily do it with base SAS (using either a data step or proc sql or some other method).